# Wiremock 2.x in Scala

Tags: scala, wiremock

I am trying to use Wiremock 2.1.6 from Scala. However, something has changed in the types of the mapping builders, so that scalac cannot typecheck it anymore.

The first stubbing example in the documentation:

```java
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            .withBody("Hello world!")));
```

results in this error when compiling:

```
type mismatch;
    found   : ?0(in value <local TestSpec>) where type ?0(in value <local TestSpec>) <: AnyRef
    required: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.RemoteMappingBuilder[_ <: AnyRef, _ <: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.ScenarioMappingBuilder]
    get(urlEqualTo("some/thing")).willReturn(
```

The method `willReturn` is defined in the `RemoteMappingBuilder` interface

```java
public interface RemoteMappingBuilder<M extends RemoteMappingBuilder, S extends ScenarioMappingBuilder> {
    ...
    M willReturn(ResponseDefinitionBuilder responseDefBuilder);
}
```

It seems to me that Scala is not happy about the generic interface `RemoteMappingBuilder` being used without type parameters in `M extends RemoteMappingBuilder`.

Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found any workarounds? For now I am using 2.0.8-beta as last working version (with `MappingBuilder` instead of `RemoteMappingBuilder`)

Comment: No, haven't found anything. Will try with the older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast to `RemoteMappingBuilder[_,_]` like this:

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        .withBody("Hello world!")).asInstanceOf[RemoteMappingBuilder[_,_]])
```

Unfortunately this is needed every time calling functions of generic `RemoteMappingBuilder` interface, e.g.:

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
    .withQueryParam("some_parameter", equalTo(paramValue)).asInstanceOf[RemoteMappingBuilder[_,_]]
    .willReturn(aResponse()
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        .withBody("Hello world!")).asInstanceOf[RemoteMappingBuilder[_,_]])
```

Comment: Are you able to tell why Scala is not inferring the type like Java would?

Comment: As far as I understood the only implementing class ``MappingBuilder`` is package private and cannot be seen by compiler. 
It is possible also to cast to more specific interface ``ScenarioMappingBuilder``. Both solutions are pretty ugly - there was some idea Wiremock maintainers tried to achieve with those generic types, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in the latest release: https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/pull/482